# how to start angular service (post, get and delete)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I generate a code with editor.swagger and I want to code a GUI with angular for that code. Since I'm newbie in angular, I dind't understand well how to start programming. I first decide to create 3 files : index.html, index.js and service.js.

Here is a part of my code :

I don't know if it's the good beginning or not. But the problem is that I don't have any idea how what I should do for POST and DELETE. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the standard 4 methods in Angluar JS(POST,GET,PUT,DELETE). To use these in angular you have to use the $http service that angular provides. To find out more about it check their documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

From the [Angular $http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> Complete list of shortcut methods:

```
$http.get
$http.head
$http.post
$http.put
$http.delete
$http.jsonp
$http.patch
```

You can also use the method parameter in the `$http` service. So `$http(method: 'DELETE', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.service('apiService', ['$http', function($http){

    this.get = function(){
        return $http.get(URL);
    };

    this.delete = function(id){
        return $http.delete(URL, id);
    }

    this.post = function(data){
        return $http.post(URL, data);
    }

}]);

app.controller('controller', ['$scope', 'apiService', function($scope, apiService){

     var getData = apiService.get().success(function(){

     });

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $resource and return it as a service.

```
app.factory('factoryResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
var resource = {
    getResource: function(context) {
        var rsc = $resource(context, {}, {'update': {method: 'PUT'}});

        return rsc;
    }
};

return resource; }])
```

In your controller you should inject the newly created service as below:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, factoryResource) {
    $scope.resource = factoryResource.getResource('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects');
    $scope.resource.save(object, successCallback, errorCallback); //post
    $scope.resource.query(successCallback, errorCallback); //get all
    $scope.resource.get({id: object.id}, successCallback, errorCallback); //get a specific object
    $scope.resource.delete({id: object.id}, successCallback, errorCallback); //delete
}
```

Hope this helps;

Answer (score -1):

Basically we have 4 method for a REST operation

1. Create (POST)-- To Create a new User (just for an example, it can be anything)
2. Read  (GET)   -- To get all users
3. Update (PUT)  -- To update a user's property
4. Delete (DELETE)  -- To delete a user
   Let me know if you need further clarification.

In angular using service you can do that.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.factory('UserService', function($http){
    var user = {};
    user.post = function(data){
        return $http.post('url', data);
    }
    user.get = function(){
        return $http.get('url');
    }
    user.delete = function(id){
        return $http.delete('url');
    }
     user.update = function(id, data){
        return $http.put('url', data);
    }
    return user
});

app.controller('Controller', function('UserService'){
    // Get
    UserService.get().success(function(){

    });
    UserService.post(data).success(function(){

    });
    UserService.delete(id).success(function(){

    });
    UserService.get(id, data).success(function(){

    });

})
```

This can be done easily through **$resource**, if you URL is proper rest.

Comment: yeah, I know that. The problem is that I don't know how to write these methods in angular. If I should put them in the same controller or not? etc.